# Подключение шаблонов Underscore.js

Tags: шаблоны, javascript

Можно ли шаблоны подключать как отдельные файлы? Как-то так, например:

```
script type="text/template" src="templates/main.inc".
```

Если подключать таким образом, то шаблон определяется, но контент из него не выводиться.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так оно не умеет.

Можно решить чем-то в духе такого:

```
var template = null;
$.get('/templates/main.inc', function(template_text){
    template = _.template(template_text);
});
```